# Angular2: moduleId not needed anymore?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I use angular cli 1.0.0-beta.21and I've observed that when I generate a component it not use the `moduleId: module.id` anymore for relative paths. More, if I try to use it it gives an error:

> Uncaught Error: moduleId should be a string in "Page1NinjaComponent". See [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html#!#set-the-moduleid-) for more information.

**Component**

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-page1-ninja',
  templateUrl: 'page1-ninja.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['page1-ninja.component.css']
})
```

Is not required anymore?

Comment: Are you using commonjs module in tsconfig?

Comment: I see that in `tsconfig.json` is set : `"module": "commonjs"` - yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build your application as `commonjs`, modules are loaded with a suitable package loader such as `systemjs` and `webpack` which is mainly used by `Angular CLI`. Thus there is an alternative way for loading relative paths. See [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html) and [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-relative-paths.html#!#why-default) for more informations.

Comment: so angular-cli use the webpack way. Just to know - what sould be done to work with moduleId again?

Comment: nothing, just if you take a look on the hyperlinked docs , you'll find that there is an alternative way, you wont need it anymore:), I do not know, maybe you should not use `commonjs`. should be customized then.